# Are there hash algorithms with variable length output?

Tags: hash, algorithm-design, one-way-function

I understand that for example MD5 produces a 128 bit hash value from a given text of variable size. My question is if there is a hash-like algorithm that will produce a hash value where one can specify the length of the outcome? So one would specify that that given any input the hash value (output) should be say 1000 bits.

For example, I would like to produce a hash value of the same length as the input. One way that I had thought of doing this would be to just encrypt the input somehow, but this would probably be easy to break, since one would just decrypt.

Another way I had thought about would be to divide the input up into say 128 bit chunks and then do MD5 (or some other hash) on each part and then just create one long string with the hashes of all the strings. However, I can see that a change in the input in one byte only would change 128 bits of the output.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As D.W. notes, you can use the output of any conventional hash function to key a stream cipher (or a block cipher in a streaming mode like CTR), and then take the output of the cipher as your digest.

However, there has been a trend in modern hash function design to support arbitrary-length output directly, without the need for additional layers.  For example, the [cryptographic sponge](http://sponge.noekeon.org/) construction has this feature built in: you absorb the input into the sponge and then squeeze as much output out of it as you want.

Out of the five [SHA-3 competition finalists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_hash_function_competition), two — [Skein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skein_%28hash_function%29) and [Keccak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keccak) — support arbitrary output lengths.  Keccak does this by virtue of being a sponge hash; Skein instead internally uses a system very similar to D.W.'s CTR-mode construction, reusing its Threefish tweakable block cipher for both input compression and output generation.

**Update:** Since this answer was originally written, Keccak was selected as the SHA-3 competition winner and [standardized](http://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.202) as SHA-3 by the NIST.  The arbitrary output length variant of Keccak was standardized as two "extendable-output functions" (XOFs) named [SHAKE128 and SHAKE256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3#Instances) (where the numbers 128 and 256 denote the internal sponge capacity in bits).

Comment: Actually, the SHA-3 schedule is "by the end of 2012" so it's about where one would expect.

Comment: Note that the arbitrary output length unfortunately is not considered by NIST, so it remains to be seen if this feature will receive as much scrutiny as the use of specific size hashes. And if a finalist actually contains the feature, then it may not be present in many implementations, as the method of generating a random output is not defined.

Comment: As a note to future readers, here we are a year after most of the answers to this question were written, and the SHA-3 contest has now been decided. Keccak was selected.

Comment: The arbitrary-output variant of Keccak was since then standardized as SHAKE128 + SHAKE256.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now the new question has a real dupe.

Answer (score 18):

Sure.  If you want a $b$-bit hash of the message $m$, then use the first $b$ bits of AES-CTR(SHA256($m$)).  That'll do the trick.

In other words, compute SHA256($m$) and treat the resulting 256-bit string as a 256-bit AES key.  Next, use AES in counter mode (with this key) to generate an unending stream of pseudorandom bits.  Take the first $b$ bits from this stream, and call it your hash.  (Make sure you don't treat the IV as part of this stream, as the IV won't be pseudorandom.  You may need to manually remove the IV first before taking the first $b$ bits.)

**Security.** This should be secure as long as $b \ge 160$ or so.  In particular, a collision attack is expected to take about $2^{\min(b,256)/2}$ steps of computation, given our current knowledge of AES and SHA256.  So, as long as you don't choose a value of $b$ that is too small, you should be good.  Choosing a value of $b$ larger than 256 does not give you greater security against collisions, but that's irrelevant: the level of security will already be way more than enough for any reasonable application, so you're good.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but can you pass a zero-filled buffer as plain-text (of size `b` bits) to an AES block cipher (say CBC or whatever), use the SHA-256 hash to derive the key and initialization vector, and then take the first `b` bits of cipher-text to be used as your output?  Is this just as secure?  See https://gist.github.com/4600432 for Node.js implementation.

Comment: @BMiner, it depends upon the mode.  For CBC mode, this will work as long as you make sure to first remove the IV (since the IV won't be random), and take the first $b$ bits of the remaining ciphertext.  I would expect something similar to hold for other reasonable modes too but I haven't thought about it carefully.

Comment: thanks for your response. What did you mean by, "make sure to first remove the IV?"  [In Node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password), if you pass a "password" into the Cipher's constructor, a key and IV is derived using [EVP_BytesToKey](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html). This means that the IV won't be random, but isn't that the idea?  If the IV was random, you wouldn't get consistent, predictable hash results?

Comment: @BMiner, sometimes some crypto libraries will generate the IV for you and include the IV in the ciphertext.  In other words, when you encrypt, you pass in a key and a message, and you get back a ciphertext, where the ciphertext includes the IV somewhere in it.  If your library is like that, you need to remove the IV (and make sure that the IV always starts at 0).  This gets easier if you implement AES-CTR yourself, so you can force it to start at IV 0 and make sure that the output only includes the generated pseudorandom stream (and not the IV).

Comment: So what if i want a hash output that would range from $[0,360]$?If it was an integer then this is totally insecure as we need roughly 9bits. But can we extend the output from 9 bits to 160 by assuming that the integer part would always be 9 bits and then the other 151bits would be used for precision? And i do not care of hashing the same input to the same output.So it resembles that i am in need of a variable out pseudorandom generator

Comment: @curious, that's a different question, which is probably best answered separatately, but the concise answer is: treat the output of SHA256(m) as a 256-bit integer, reduce it modulo 360, and use the remainder a syour random number.

Comment: @D.W. But is this secure?In the sense that there are only 360 possible values that can be brute forced easily

Comment: @curious, again, ask a new, separate question -- and make sure to follow best practices before doing so (e.g., searching to make sure it hasn't been answered before). This is not a discussion forum.  One question per question.  I'm not going to answer any new questions posed in the comment threads.

Comment: Isn't IV = counter in `AES-CTR`? I am interested in the same question as @Thomas

Comment: @Dims, Yes? I'm not 100% sure I understood what you're asking, so when you have a new question, I recommend asking via the 'Ask Question' button rather than by posting a comment here.

Answer (score 10):

In general, each combination of a (secure) hash function for input with a (deterministic) pseudo random number generator for output will work here - one "state of the art" example is the one given by D.W. (using AES-CTR as PRNG and SHA-256 as hash).

Another way is similar to what [PBKDF-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) does to have output with the right length: hash the input (or a hash of the input) multiple times, each with a different prefix, and concatenate these outputs:

```
output = H(1 || M) || H(2 || M) || H(3 || M) || ...
```

(One could say that this is a special case of the general case before, at least when H is already a hash of the original message.)

There are some hash functions with a "arbitrary output length" mode, such as [Skein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skein_%28hash_function%29) (one of the SHA-3 candidates). (This mode of Skein internally works just like the scheme above, but it is hidden in one standardized primitive, you don't have to build this yourself.)

The actual winner of the SHA-3 competition, Keccak, also has a mode with arbitrary-length output (by just squeezing its sponge as long as needed to produce the required output), which was standardized as [SHAKE128 and SHAKE256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3#Instances) (the number indicates the security level for collision resistance, if the output length is at least double as long).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are hash-like algorithms that are able to produce variable-length outputs without any extra efforts. This is something "[sponge functions](http://sponge.noekeon.org/)" do. One such sponge construction is [KeccaK](http://keccak.noekeon.org/) which is one of five finalists in the SHA-3 competition.

Comment: What is the hash value of SHA-3? or how big a hash value do sha3 produce?

Comment: SHA3 is not yet standardized, the resulting digests are therefore not available. Keccak test values range between 1 bit and 1599 bits in theory with a single "squeeze"

Comment: Two "arbitrary output length" variants were standardized as SHAKE128 and SHAKE256.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious about your purpose.  Generally the primary operation involving a message digest is ultimately to compare two digest values.  Hashing passwords allows comparing the digest values instead of carrying the super secret password around the systems.  Hashing messages allows the transmitter and sender to verify the data was correctly received without resending the whole message.  Encrypting a hash with a private key allows them to be decrypted with the public key and then compared to verify the signer's identity.  Even hashing strings in a database allows an efficient indexed search by comparing and sorting digest values.

In every case of comparison, having the digest values be of equal size enables the comparison - unequal sizes would never result in an equal result.

If it's a size constraint, a cryptographically secure digest value can always be truncated with the understanding that there is a corresponding loss in fidelity.  (A non secure digest algorithm might not have the bit dispersal properties that would make such an assumption safe.)

But you've said you want a "larger" digest.  When I think about the meaning of digest, to me that is a "summary", which is always smaller than that which it summarizes.  What are you hoping to gain by making it larger?  Is it a matter of not trusting in the anti-collision properties of 2^256 possibilities?  You have piqued my curiosity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since you asked: The reason for my questions wasn't deep at all. I had thought about padding of keys/passwords, and was thinking that instead of padding key, one could just generate a hash of a specific length of a key. Thereby all key lengths should be "allowed", but I don't know if this is secure. I will probably ask a question about this later after I have thought more about it.

Comment: I see what you were going for.  Random bytes are now generally used for key padding instead of a fixed value, to avoid providing a crib to an attacker.  The key attribute to those bytes is unpredictability so they can't be used against you.  I can see why a hash could be something you'd consider using instead of random values, but it would still have to be the hash of something random so the attacker couldn't use it.  When you get that deep, cryptographically random bytes are already a very good solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the other answers are from before SHA-3 was standardized, I'll add another update: Keccak was chosen for SHA-3. The standard doesn't define any extendable output features for SHA-3 itself, I think because they wanted it to be a drop-in replacement for SHA-2. But it does define two closely related functions, SHAKE128 and SHAKE256, which support extendable output. These are fairly widely available, including in OpenSSL and in Python's standard `hashlib` module.

The BLAKE family of hashes also supports extendable output, via either [BLAKE2X](https://www.blake2.net/blake2x.pdf) or [BLAKE3](https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3-specs/blob/master/blake3.pdf).

The HKDF construction also supports extendable output, using any underlying hash function. Unfortunately, it's standardized with a maximum output length of 255 times the underlying digest size. It seems like it would've been easy to use 8 bytes instead of 1 byte for the block counter, and I'm not sure why they didn't.